# Ionic Collection Repeat Scroll not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to show a list with collection repeat, it does output the list, but it's not scrollable. any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

thats my code;

```
<div class="list" >
    <div class="form-item"
         ng-class="{'form-item--child': airport.isChild}"
         collection-repeat="airport in airports track by airport.id"
         collection-item-width="1080"
         collection-item-height="200" ng-show="airportName && airportName.length > 0">
        <ion-radio ng-model="obj.value" ng-value="airport.value" on-tap="selectAirport(airport)">{{ airport.label }}<i class="icon-select"></i></ion-radio>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item" collection-repeat="airport in favorites track by airport.id"
         collection-item-width="1080" collection-item-height="200"  ng-hide="airportName.length > 0">
        <ion-radio ng-model="obj.value" ng-value="airport.value" on-tap="selectAirport(airport)">{{ airport.label }}<i class="icon-select"></i></ion-radio>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a height to your div

Comment: @Sajeetharan I tried to add to the `list` div height, still didn't work.

Comment: can you create plunker?

Answer (score 6):

be sure ionic js control your scroll : `overflow-scroll="false"`

and wrap your item in ion-list

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="false">
     <ion-list>
           <ion-item
               class="form-item" 
               collection-repeat="airport in favorites track by airport.id"
               collection-item-width="1080" collection-item-height="200"  ng-hide="airportName.length > 0">
               <ion-radio ng-model="obj.value" ng-value="airport.value" on-tap="selectAirport(airport)">{{ airport.label }}<i class="icon-select"></i></ion-radio>
           </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```